# AES decrypting incorrectly

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm trying to rewrite AES code i found on internet. Trying to change modes from ECB to CBC. Code doesn't give me any errors while encrypting or decrypting, yet it return incorrect decrypted plaintext. You can see output [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HswRM.jpg).

```
public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, SecretKey secret) throws InvalidKeyException{
    
    try{
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret); //without this line, iv = null
        byte[] iv = cipher.getIV();
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(iv, 0, iv.length);
        byte[] cipherT = cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes());
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(cipherT, 0, cipherT.length);
        cipherT = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(cipherT));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
} 
     
public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, SecretKey secret) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    byte[] CipherByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt);
    iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(CipherByte, 0, iv.length);

    CipherByte = Arrays.copyOfRange(CipherByte, 16, CipherByte.length);
    try{
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(CipherByte));
    
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried making iv to be all zero, so i wouldn't need to add it to cipher text

```
byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

and read it while decrypting, but the output is the same. I can't figure it out, i don't understand, is it encryption problem or decryption.

Comment: What do you mean by "the output is the same"? The same as what?

Comment: By saying "the output is the same" i mean cipher text doesn't get decrypted correctly, and the output looks like random bytes. Sorry for not making it clear

Comment: In `encrypt()` the second call to `cipher.init()` doesn't do anything. Then later in the method you doubly encrypt the data, the second time in this line: `return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(cipherT));`

Comment: Please do **not use a fixed IV** as it makes your encryption **UNSECURE**.

Comment: @President James K. Polk, thank you, i totally missed that, now it decrypts correctly.

Comment: @Michael Fehr, im not planning to use fixed iv, im adding iv to the first 16 bytes of cipher. With fixed iv i was just testing, to see if iv was the problem in my code (it wasn't).

Comment: @President James K. Polk, can you post this as a answer, so i could mark it as answered.